# Как вставить в таблицу связи значения из таблиц сущностей?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, oracle11g

Как добавить в таблицу связи данные с таблиц сущностей?

То есть, например, один столбец в таблице связи должен быть заполнен значениями из таблицы сущности.

Как это делать через `INSERT...INTO`?

Comment: А что такое _данные с таблиц сущностей_, не подскажите?

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте на основе следующего воспроизводимого примера:

```
create or replace type person force as object (id int, name varchar2 (8))
/
create or replace type address as object (id int, address varchar2 (16))
/
create table persons of person (id primary key)
/
create table addresses of address (id primary key)
/
create table address_person (persid int, addrid int)
/
insert all 
into persons values   (person  ( 1, 'name1'))
into addresses values (address (99, 'address99'))
select null from dual
/
```

Вставить данные в таблицу связей можно так:

```
insert into address_person 
    select p.id, a.id
    from persons p, addresses a
    where p.name = 'name1' and a.address = 'address99'
```

Вот, что получится:

```
select p.id, p.name, a.id, a.address
from persons p
join address_person m on m.persid = p.id
join addresses a on a.id = m.addrid 
/

        ID NAME             ID ADDRESS         
---------- -------- ---------- ----------------
         1 name1            99 address99
```

Answer (score 2):

Связи между таблицами, содержащие сущности объектов, обычно реализуются не через значения их атрибутов, а через ссылки на сами сущности, полученые функцией `REF`. В выборке отпадает нужда в соединении таблиц посредством `JOIN`.

Пример со вставкой в таблицу связи (с остальными данными на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8c942beec86183ed722741a4a202386f)):

```
create table address_person (
    pers ref person scope is persons, addr ref address scope is addresses)
/
insert into address_person 
    select ref (p), ref (a)
    from persons p, addresses a
    where p.id = 1 and a.id = 99
/
```

Сам запрос и его результат:

```
select r.pers.id, r.pers.name, r.addr.id, r.addr.address
from address_person r 
/

   PERS.ID PERS.NAM    ADDR.ID ADDR.ADDRESS    
---------- -------- ---------- ----------------
         1 name1            99 address99
```